# VB.net use string in Directory Path?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I apologise for my lack of basic VB.net knowledge but I'm looking to use the equivalent of %systemdrive% to find the drive containing Windows to check for an existing directory in VB.net - so I have the below.

```
Dim systemPath As String = Mid(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), 1, 3)
        If Not Directory.Exists("'systemPath'\MyFolder") Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory("'systemPath'\MyFolder")
        End If
```

Can someone help with using the systemPath string in the directory query? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should write

```
Dim systemPath As String = Mid(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), 1, 3)
If Not Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(systemPath, "MyFolder")) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(systemPath, "MyFolder"))
End If
```

You could get the environment variable called %SYSTEMDRIVE% with Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable, but then the results obtained should be manually combined with current directory separator char (`"\"`) because I have not found any way to convince Path.Combine to build a valid path with only the system drive (I.E. `C:` )

```
Dim sysDrive = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemDrive") 
Dim myPath = sysDrive & Path.DirectorySeparatorChar & "MyFolder"
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first snippet. My problem is learning how to combing strings in to a field that has (""). Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

IO.Path has methods that should be used IMHO

```
    Dim sysDrive As String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemDrive") & IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
    Dim myPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(sysDrive, "FolderName")
```